# do loop on sas but not with a macro

Tags: sas

It is a simple one but I'm a struggling a bit.

What I have :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

I want to remove the v0 , v1 and etc.

I'm using this piece of code

```
data IndieDay20140704;
set IndieDay20140704;
do i=1 to 5;
VAR1=tranwrd(var1,"v&i","");
end;
run;
```

It is not working correctly as it is giving me this instead (see below) plus the error 
`WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.`

[image]

Questions:

1) Do I need a macro?
2) Why the error?

Many thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error because you're (unintentionally) using macro variable `i`, that you did not initialize.

I guess the idea of `tranwrd` is to remove words in `VAR2`, `VAR3`.. from `VAR1`.
The logical error is to do it also for `VAR1` itself.

Check if this helps (using array):

```
data IndieDay20140704;
length VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR3 VAR5 $10;
VAR1 = 'TEST IT';VAR5 = 'TEST';
output;
VAR1 = 'STEST IT';VAR5 = 'TEST';
output;
run;

data IndieDay20140704_modified / view= IndieDay20140704_modified;
set IndieDay20140704;
    array vals VAR1 - VAR5;
    do i=1 to dim(vals);
        if i ne 1 then VAR1=tranwrd(var1,trim(vals(i)),"");
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Here I'm creating a SAS view on top of table (not a good idea to overwrite the source).
Also I think you should `trim()` the values from VAR2,VAR3... depending on what you want to achieve and what's in the data.

EDIT:
here the version with 'v0', 'v1'...'v5' strings:

```
data IndieDay20140704;
length VAR1$10;
VAR1 = 'TEST v0';
output;
VAR1 = 'TEST v11';
output;
VAR1 = 'TEST v1';
output;
run;

data IndieDay20140704_modified / view= IndieDay20140704_modified;
set IndieDay20140704;
    org_var1 = var1;
    do i=0 to 5;
        var1 =tranwrd(var1, catt('v', put(i, 1. -L)),"");
    end;
run;
```

`catt('v', put(i, 1. -L))` concatenates string 'v' and the result of `put`.
`put(i, 1. -L))` converts numeric variable `i` to text using plain numeric format `w.d`, `1.` used here - enough for single digit numbers, `-L` left aligns the result

Comment: Hi Vajda, many thanks for your answer. However, as I said in my question, I want to remove the v0 , v1 etc ... 

I have put the i for looping through that and removing the v{i} sequentially starting from v0 until v5. Am I clear in my explanation?

Comment: You mean strings 'v0', 'v1'...?

Comment: Ok, not that flawed actually. Many thanks for your help. Can you explain a bit the following , please :

1) Can you explain ? (var1, catt('v', put(i, 1. -L)),"")

Comment: Why not simply use `cats('v',i)` instead of `catt(...)`?

Comment: Without PUT your relying on implicit conversion (using BEST12. format I believe), for small numbers ok, I just don't do that). Yes, CATS will do same as CATT with left aligned PUT - I'm just used to CATT. Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, there are many others and this may not work if your data has a lot of variability.

```
data have;
length VAR1$10;
VAR1 = 'fic19v0.csv';
output;
VAR1 = 'fic19v1.cs';
output;
run;


data want ;
set have;
original_var=var1;
var1=substr(var1, 1, index(var1, ".")-3)||".csv";

run;
```

Comment: Hi Reese, many thanks for that one.

I knew some stuff can be resolved without coding !!

Can you explain a bit more `var1=substr(var1, 1, index(var1, ".")-3)||".csv";` , please?

Comment: Basically take the portion of the string before the . and add the .csv to the end. The index finds the period in the string and the -3 tells the substring function to take the string from position 1 to 3 before the ..